# Specify different body class for each page in partial view header

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm newby to MVC and I want to have different body class for each view.
My header is a partial view and @RenderSection does not work for it.

_Layout.cshtml:

```
    @{ 
        Html.RenderAction("GetHeader", "Main");
    }

    @RenderBody()

    @{
        Html.RenderAction("GetFooter", "Main");
    }
```

_HeaderLayout.cshtml:

```
    //...
    <body class=" here must be specified class different for each view">
    //...
```

MainController:

```
    public class MainController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult GetHeader()
        {
            return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/_HeaderLayout.cshtml");
        }

        public ActionResult GetFooter()
        {
            return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/_FooterLayout.cshtml");
        }
    }
```

Any idea please?

Answer (score 1):

I would do it in two ways:

1. Create a base ViewModel class for all the view models used in your app and add a property for the `BodyClass`, then implement it in the Partial View.
2. Add a property in the `ViewBag` dictionary before returning the partial view.

Examples:
1. Base class

```
public class BaseViewModel
{
   public string BodyClass {get; set;}
}
```

Usage:

**Base Class:**

in partial view:

```
@model BaseViewModel
///...
<body class="@Model.BodyClass">
```

in controller:

```
 public ActionResult GetHeader()
 {
     var vm = new BaseViewModel { BodyClass= "test-class" };
     return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/_HeaderLayout.cshtml", vm);
 }
```

**In `ViewBag`:**

```
public ActionResult GetHeader()
{
     ViewBag[SomeConstantStringValue] = "test-class";
     return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/_HeaderLayout.cshtml");
}
```

in partial view:

```
<body class="@ViewBag[SomeConstantStringValue]">
```

Remember that you always have to specify that ViewBag value, otherwise you'll get an error.

Comment: Thanks @mihail but HeaderLayout will load before any view and BodyClass can not to be set in GetHeader of MainController, it must set in each controller of each view seperately. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Mihail Stancescu answer is probably best, but if you don't want a view model for each controller method, you could make use of a helper function instead. Either way though, your're going to probably have to make your own method that decides which class to return (see BodyClassForTabAndMethod() below).

Create a Helper class (if you don't have a suitable one already):

```
public static class Helper
{
    public static string BodyClassForTabAndMethod()
    {
        string[] selectedTabAndMethod = GetSelectedTabAndMethod();

        string bodyClass = "";

        // Change the below switch statements based upon the controller/method name.
        switch (selectedTabAndMethod[0])
        {
            case "home":
                switch (selectedTabAndMethod[1])
                {
                    case "index":
                        return "IndexClass";
                    case "about":
                        return "AboutClass";
                    case "contact":
                        return "ContactClass";
                }
                break;
            case "account":
                switch (selectedTabAndMethod[1])
                {
                    case "login":
                        return "LoginClass";
                    case "verifycode":
                        return "VerifyCodeClass";
                }
                break;
        }

        return bodyClass;
    }

    public static string[] GetSelectedTabAndMethod()
    {
        string[] selectedTabAndMethod = new string[2]; // Create array and set default values.
        selectedTabAndMethod[0] = "home";
        selectedTabAndMethod[1] = "index";

        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.LocalPath.Length > 1)
        {
            // Get the selected tab and method (without the query string).
            string tabAndMethod = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.LocalPath.ToLower();

            // Remove the leading/trailing "/" if found.
            tabAndMethod = ((tabAndMethod.Substring(0, 1) == "/") ? tabAndMethod.Substring(1) : tabAndMethod);
            tabAndMethod = ((Right(tabAndMethod, 1) == "/") ? tabAndMethod.Substring(0, tabAndMethod.Length - 1) : tabAndMethod);

            // Convert into an array.
            if (tabAndMethod.Count(s => s == '/') == 1)
            {
                string[] split = tabAndMethod.Split('/');
                selectedTabAndMethod[0] = split[0];
                selectedTabAndMethod[1] = split[1];
            }
        }

        return selectedTabAndMethod;
    }

    public static string Right(string value, int length)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) return string.Empty;

        return ((value.Length <= length) ? value : value.Substring(value.Length - length));
    }
}
```

And then in your view:
`<body class="@Helper.BodyClassForTabAndMethod()">`

Answer (score 0):

I reached to a solution for my own question, very simply:

In Global.asax: //or any other class which loading at start

```
    public static class WrrcGlobalVariables
    {
        //any other global variables...

        public static string BodyClass { get; set; }
    }
```

In any Controller and before returning view/partial view:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //some codes...

        WrrcGlobalVariables.BodyClass = "HomePage";

        return View();
    }
```

and in _HeaderLayout.cshtml:

```
    <body class="@WrrcGlobalVariables.BodyClass">
```

Answer (score 0):

Both the approaches given by Mihail Stancescu are correct, however there is one more way to have a default value for it and custom value only when required. Also you should use RenderPartial as well for your case instead of RenderAction if all you're doing is rendering the partial without any extra logic which requires a child controller.

In _Layout.cshtml

```
@Html.Partial("_HeaderLayout")
@RenderBody()
@Html.Partial("_FooterLayout")
```

In _HeaderLayout.cshtml

```
<body class="@ViewBag[SomeConstantStringValue]">
```

In _ViewStart.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag[SomeConstantStringValue] = ViewBag[SomeConstantStringValue] ?? "default-class";
}
```

Then anywhere in any view or controller set this ViewBag value, this way you'll ensure a guaranteed default value to prevent null reference exceptions